# Non-hardocded <option> for html, instead have the <option> display local files

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

So I am building a local **javascript** web app run off of tomcat, the user will select a file that I currently have hardcoded in as an `<option>` in html, which I do not want to do. I want the html page to go to a specified folder on my local machine and give the various options that the user can select from as files from my local machine, and I have not been able to find anywhere that someone has done this.

Below is the code that I currently have, I have gotten it to work where I can select an item and the data I need is passed to where I want it passed to.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Crom - Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>
 <form name="selectForm" method="post" action="listOfFormsServlet">

  <select name="ListOfForms" size="10">

   <option value="45 Day Letter Temp">45 Day Letter Temp</option>

   <option value="IA Initial Contact Letter Template">IA
    Initial Contact Letter Template</option>

   <option value="IA Name List">IA Name List</option>

   <option value="Initial Contact Letter Temp">Initial Contact
    Letter Temp</option>

   <option value="Recoverable Depreciation Letter for Cov A and B Temp">Recoverable
    Depreciation Letter for Cov A and B Temp</option>

   <option value="Recoverable Depreciation Letter for Cov C">Recoverable
    Depreciation Letter for Cov C</option>
  </select> <input type="submit" value="Continue">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot interact the the filesystem on the client.

Comment: You'll need to use server side technology for this. You can't do it in basic HTML.

Comment: When you say _go to a specified folder on my local machine_, what are you considering the _local machine_, the client or the server?

Answer (score 1):

As SLacks has commented. You cannot get any information from the file system using client side applications (JS). You will need to implement a server side based language such as PHP, Ruby etc in order to get such information.

Javascript is a client side language which runs in the browser. It has no idea about anything outside of the browser environment.